# Jquery: apply class to all text on the webpages

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the jquery plugin [trocar](https://github.com/kileras/jquery.trocar.js/tree/master) to make the text of a webapge editable on the fly.

for example

```
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="text-poi" tabindex="-1">
             This text is editable.
            </p>
        </div>
```

In above i have added a class, which uses by following js code to make that editable.

js code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.trocar.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(".text-poi").trocar({
        'on': 'focus',
        'off': 'blur',
        'endOnEnter': true,
        'filterPaste': true
    });
    </script>
```

On webpage i want every pieces of text to editable. 
On way is to add `text-poi` class to every single text element , but would be tiring.

Is there any better way to do that ?

Comment: Isn't the `.trocar()` plugin a replacement of `contenteditable` attribute? why not just use jquery for applying the attribute everywhere?

Comment: just out of curiosity, by " i want every pieces of text to editable." do you mean just the <p> tags and respective tags? If that is the case then instead of giving a class name "text-poi" to every thing, you can just specify the tags to apply the plugin on? like $ p.trocar({...})

Comment: @sai: i mean every text , whether it is in <a>, <p> or <h1> etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and safer solution would be to reference only tipical text tags, I would avoid * selector:

```
$('p, span, h1, h2').trocar({[...]});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('*').trocar({
    'on': 'focus',
    'off': 'blur',
    'endOnEnter': true,
    'filterPaste': true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did and it worked for me

```
<body class="edit">
   < all your content here >
</body>
```

and in the script section at the bottom before the < /body> tag ....

```
<script>
$ ('.edit').trocar({
    'on': 'always',
    'off': 'blur',
    'endOnEnter': true,
    'filterPaste': true
});
</script>
```

hope this helps